# Is there a Node.js equivalent of Perl's WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

I'm searching a module for Node which would be similar to [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) for Perl. Or even better to [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm).

- The main functionality would be to find and submit form by name,
  class or id.
- The ability to handle cookies would be great
- and the ability to handle Javascript would be perfect.

If anyone had an idea of something similar, or in which direction I could search, that would really be appreciated.

Comment: Why would this question be down voted?

Comment: Some users are "special" (like ralph). +1 for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you're looking for is a scriptable/headless browser. In decreasing order of popularity, the options are:

- [Google Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) - "Node library which provides a high-level API to control Chrome or Chromium"
- [Zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie) - more lightweight; "Insanely fast, headless full-stack testing using Node.js"
- [slimerjs](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs) - scriptable Firefox. No commits since March 2018.
- [mechanize-js](https://github.com/srveit/mechanize-js/issues/4), which lacks documentation and has far less traction than any of the above alternatives

### Abandoned projects

- [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) - headless WebKit.
- [chimera](https://github.com/deanmao/node-chimera) - abandoned since 2013

Answer (score 1):

Try [mechanize-js](https://github.com/srveit/mechanize-js) - the name says it all...

Answer (score 0):

The closest tool I have found for now is [zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie).

Apparently it is not exactly ready for production (and may never be) as it is a testing tool.
Nevertheless it seems that it is the closest match for the functionality needed (and it supports JS!)

Answer (score 0):

you can embed perl script in node.js use:

> npm install exec_perl

see: https://github.com/tlqtangok/exec_perl